# Not able to get path and method from a HTTP request in C

Tags: c, sockets, http

My server code is based on [this](http://www.lowtek.com/sockets/select.html), although I modifed the `deal_with_data` function, looking like this:

```
void dealWithData (int list, void (*callback)(struct Request, int socket)) {
    char buffer[8196];
    int n;

    if (sock_gets(connectlist[list], buffer, 8196) < 0) {
        close(connectlist[list]);
        connectlist[list] = 0;
    } else {
        n = read(connectlist[list], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        buffer[n] = 0;

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        struct Request req = parseRequest(buffer, n);
        callback(req, connectlist[list]);

        close(connectlist[list]);
        connectlist[list] = 0;
    }

};
```

The data I get from the printf  is this:

```
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

The first line which contains the path, method and protocol does not appear, I guess is received but I don't know why is not getted, maybe is because the asynchronous functions? I do an HTTP server in a synchronous way, and it gets that line perfectly. Maybe is beacuse the way I read the socket dat?

Thank's advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly `sock_gets()` is reading your first line, and then you're just overwriting it on your subsequent call to `read()`. Try changing to:

```
} else {
    printf("%s\n", buffer);    /*  <--- Add this line  */

    n = read(connectlist[list], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    buffer[n] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

and you should see the first line.

Alternatively, to get it all in one string, presuming `sock_gets()` behaves like `gets()` and strips the newline:

```
} else {
    size_t offset = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[offset] = '\n';

    n = read(connectlist[list], buffer + offset + 1,
             sizeof(buffer) - offset - 1);
    buffer[n + offset + 1] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", buffer);
```

As an aside, note that under HTTP lines end with a `CRLF`. `sock_gets()` might do the conversion manually for you, but with a straight `read()` call you'll have to do the translation yourself. Otherwise, you'll be printing a bunch of `\r` characters with that `printf()` call.